# #define in header files in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, macros, c-preprocessor

I have a Global.h that looks like

```
#define NUMBERX 21
```

In AppDelegate.h I include the Global.h file. In the AppDelegate.m I include the AppDelegate.h file. But in the AppDelegate.m I can't access the NUMBERX variable.

```
ERROR: Use of undeclared indentifier 'NUMBERX'.
```

If I define NUMBERX in AppDelegate.h than it works, but I want include only the header file (Global.h) in all other header files where I want to use the NUMBERX variable.

How can I solve that?

Comment: Does it work in AppDelegate.h?

Comment: Yes. But that's not what I want. I want only define the variable one time for the whole project.

Comment: No, I mean can you access NUMBERX in AppDelegate.h? Or do you get an error there too?

Comment: Does it work if you put it in the pch file?

Comment: You're making some basic mistake.  Misspelled name somewhere, the #define actually in a comment, conflicting h file names, etc.

Comment: Can this problem still arise in 2016?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using objective-c standard `#import` to include your header file, try replacing it with a "c" `#include`.

Comment: Yes, THX. This works fine. Maybe the objective-c standard `#import` is used for files with a associated .m file. My Global.h doesn't have a Global.m brother.

Comment: @TheFox - no, that's not the case - Objective-C protocols are just header files with no corresponding implementation files, and they work.

Comment: @Abizern - Ah ok, but the problem was definitely the `#import` instead of `#include`. Thx all for your answers.

Comment: Does this still apply in 2016?

Answer (score 1):

This should be fine, assuming you're not `#undef`ing it before you're using it. Are you using the symbol before you include `AppDelegate.h` in the `AppDelegate.m` file? Are you using include guards that might prohibit it's inclusion?

Comment: What do you mean with include guards? No, I have no `#undef`. And yes, I include all header files at the top of each file. That means I don't use the symbol before I include the `AppDelegate.h` file.

Comment: Include guards are things like `#ifndef _SOMESYMBOL ... #endif` inside headers to prevent their double inclusion from causing errors. If you reuse the same guard symbol twice, this can cause this problem. If you're not doing that, we'll need more information (i.e. a minimal version of the files that still doesn't work).

Answer (score 0):

You have to include your Global.h file in AppDelegate.m file.

Comment: That also don't work. Only if I define the variable in AppDelegate.h it works.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not use `int const NUMBERX` then you will get code completion and compiler checking.

Apple has some pretty good guidelines on defining constants and naming them here 
[Apple Coding Guidelines - Constants](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingIvarsAndTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001284-BAJGIIJE)

Comment: Yes, of cause, there are multiple ways to realize that. My deeper sense is that I replace all `NSLOG()` with a macro defined `l()` function. In the production I have no defined `DEBUG` variable, so all log outputs are not shown.

Comment: Purely for the fact that you get code completion and compiler checking I believe that the method suggested from the Apple docs is superior to a #define. Additionally if you require the constant throughout most of your project you may consider adding the `Global.h` to your `pch` file. Defining the macro `l()` would certainly save you a few keystrokes every now and then but it also adds baggage to your project that you need to tell anyone you collaborate with that this is what you are doing. This is why people stick to standards to make collaboration easier.